# How did Fold of Dawn get hold of Gundams?

Tags: gundam-witch-from-mercury

In the final two episodes of *Gundam: Witch From Mercury* S1, the Plant Quetta space station is attacked by the Earthian terrorist group Fold of Dawn, who have somehow obtained Gundams. Furthermore, in S2 Ep.7 (which is where I'm up to), Prospera Mercury comes across a whole stash of Gundams that apparently belong to Fold of Dawn.

I don't understand where they got all these Gundams from. My naive understanding is that all the Gundams were destroyed in the attack on Ochs Earth during the Prologue, and that Aerial is the only one left. I know that Fold of Dawn were secretly being backed by Shaddiq Zenelli, but again, I don't understand how *he* could have gotten hold of Gundams to give them to Fold of Dawn in the first place.

I think this may have been explained at some point, but there are so many different factions at play that it went completely over my head. So I'll ask simply: **how did Fold of Dawn get their hands on Gundams?** Or - assuming they got them from Shaddiq - how did *he* get his hands on Gundams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because while Ochs Earth was thought to have been disbanded, it was still operating developing Gundams for the Space Assembly League

> Ochs Earth was believed to have been disbanded by this time. However, they actually continued to operate in secret by building new Gundams, being the developers of the EDM-GA-01 Gundam Lfrith Ur and EDM-GA-02 Gundam Lfrith Thorn. They were funded in these endeavors by the Space Assembly League, who intended to use the Gundams to crack down on the Benerit Group for their continued administrative overreach. Prospera Mercury learned of their intentions and destroyed Ochs Earth's facilities at Quinharbor using the XVX-016RN Gundam Aerial Rebuild

Source: [Ochs Earth Corporation > History > A.S. 122](https://gundam.fandom.com/wiki/Ochs_Earth_Corporation#A.S._122)

But then how did Fold of Dawn get hold of them?

(SPOILERS OF THE FINAL EPISODE)

> it was likely through Shaddiq, to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Mobile_Suit_Gundam:_The_Witch_from_Mercury_episodes&oldid=1163009269#Season_2_(2023))

> *"... while Miorine announces that she has formally dissolved the Benerit Group and sold off its assets to Earth, so the Space Assembly League has no more legal authority to act. [Miorine] also threatens to publicly release **Shaddiq's confession about his secret dealings with the Space Assembly League**."*